# pySpark dataframe multi-lined

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Is it possible to store multi-lined records as a dataframe in Spark like name and address data

```
  Name         Address

 Jane        110 N H Street
             Newark
             NJ

 Janet       111  N H Street
             Newark
             NJ-640897
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep multi-lined ? ArrayType can work as well

Comment: I am importing data from a mysql database to pyspark. One of the fields is multi-lined and imported as StringType in spark, but unable to process them in Spark. The field is a collection of random texts with lots of special characters. Any solution?  I have described the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440589/pyspark-dataframe-with-multi-lined-entry